# Math.cos(Math.PI/2) returns 6.123031769111886e-17 in JavaScript & AS3?

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-3, ecmascript-5

If I'm understanding this correct, both JavaScript and ActionScript 3 works with radians.

So the expected output of the following codes would be:

```
Math.PI                 //Expected 3.141592653589793, got 3.141592653589793

Math.sin(0)             //Expected 0, got 0
Math.sin(Math.PI/2)     //Expected 1, got 1
Math.sin(Math.PI)       //Expected 0, got 1.2246063538223773e-16
Math.sin(Math.PI*3/2)   //Expected -1, got -1
Math.sin(Math.PI*2)     //Expected 0, got -2.4492127076447545e-16

Math.cos(0)             //Expected 1, got 1
Math.cos(Math.PI/2)     //Expected 0, got 6.123031769111886e-17
Math.cos(Math.PI)       //Expected -1, got -1
Math.cos(Math.PI*3/2)   //Expected 0, got -1.836909530733566e-16
Math.cos(Math.PI*2)     //Expected 1, got 1
```

This is the same behavior in Firefox, Chrome, Safari and also in Flash Professional CS5.5. I'm using Mac OS X 10.7.2.

Test:

http://jsfiddle.net/KA4VM/

Comment: And the problem is? The 0's are pretty damn close to 0. Just a precision issue I would say. Nothing wrong.

Comment: You shouldn't expect pi to be exactly `3.141592653589793` in the first place if you want exact values to be returned by sin/cos.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider reading [what every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Have you looked at the value you're getting? You're expecting 0, but you're getting something like

```
0.00000000000000012246063538223773
```

Isn't that close enough to zero for you?

Basically, you shouldn't expect binary floating point operations to be *exactly* right when your inputs can't be expressed as exact binary values - which pi/2 can't, given that it's irrational. (You shouldn't expect the results to be exact even when the inputs can be expressed exactly in binary, if the output can't be expressed exactly...)

Comment: But won't it be way more resource intensive to calculate with `6.123031769111886e-17` then with `0`?

Comment: I lost 5 minutes trying to understand why I was getting Math.cos(1.57) = 0.0007.. and Math.cos(Math.PI/2) = 6.12... Had to come here to notice there is a "e-17" at the end...

Answer (score 3):

Consider these errors are all less than `1e-15`, which is around `2**(-50)`, so we can add then subtract a number with magnitude `2**3` to round the result. So if we pick 8 as the number, we could re-define `sin` and `cos` as following:

```
function sin(x) {
  return Math.sin(x) + 8 - 8;
}

function cos(x) {
  return Math.cos(x) + 8 - 8;
}
```

This should round out the error, and is faster than `toFixed` method.

Comment: Why is magnitude 2**3 relevant? How did you get to that number?

Answer (score 2):

Math.PI is not a 100% accurate representation of pi, simply because pi is irrational and floating point numbers only go so far.

So due to rounding errors, you get extremely tiny numbers (your numbers are #.#####e-16 and #.#####e-17, which are tiny).

Nothing you can do about it but accept that 0.000000000000000006 is close enough to 0.

Answer (score 2):

Because PI is an irrational number (Real Number without beeing Rational, it's impossible to calculate with exact value.
Like Jon Skeet said, the trigonometric methods of the Math-object gets only approximate values for PI and returns an approximate value.
If the return of Zero values are important for your code, you have to round them. 
In cases like that I extend those Javascript objects by own methods for convenience:

```
Math.Sin = function(w){         
    return parseFloat(Math.sin(w).toFixed(10));
};
```

Now while you get with

```
Math.sin(Math.PI)
```

this strange result

```
> 1.2246467991473532e-16
```

you get with what you've expected

```
Math.Sin(Math.PI)
> 0
```

Do the same with the other trigonometric functions:

```
Math.Cos = function(w){ 
    return parseFloat(Math.cos(w).toFixed(10));
};
```

and so on.

Comment: That will return 1/0 for `Math.PI/4`. You should use `parseFloat(Math.sin/cos(w).toFixed(eg 5))`.

Comment: Thanks @klenium. I've edited my post following your proposal.

Answer (score 1):

So you have 1.xxxxx * 10^-16

This would be 0.0000000000000001xxx (fifteen zeros after the decimal point)

I bet that's as close enough to zero to regard it as 0.

You get that infinitesimal error because of the error in the value of pi (as you should know, it stretches out to infinite digits after the decimal point)

You haven't mentioned if you get this in AS3 or JavaScript, though