# Why does math.cos(math.pi/2) not return zero?

Tags: python, floating-point, trigonometry, pi

I came across some weird behavior by `math.cos()` (Python 3.11.0):

```
>>> import math
>>> math.cos(math.pi)  # expected to get -1
-1.0
>>> math.cos(math.pi/2)  # expected to get 0
6.123233995736766e-17
```

I suspect that floating point math might play a role in this, but I'm not sure how. And if it did, I'd assume Python just checks if the parameter equaled `math.pi/2` to begin with.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8050751/13376511) by Jon Skeet, who said:

> Basically, you shouldn't expect binary floating point operations to be exactly right when your inputs can't be expressed as exact binary values - which pi/2 can't, given that it's irrational.

But if this is true, then `math.cos(math.pi)` shouldn't work either, because it also uses the `math.pi` approximation. My question is: why does this issue only show up when `math.pi/2` is used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result for `math.cos(math.pi)` will have a similar degree of inaccuracy, however `-1.0 + 6e-17` cannot be represented in floating point precision, so you just get `-1.0`. This can be demonstrated so:

```py
>>> -1.0000_0000_0000_001
# -1.000000000000001
>>> -1.0000_0000_0000_0001
# -1.0
```

Comment: If math.pi is pi+eps, then cos(math.pi) is -1+eps^2/2+..., so you get even "worse" -1+2e-32 or so.

Comment: @LutzLehmann how do you figure that? Surely it's `-1 + (2*pi*eps + eps^2)/2 + ...`?

Comment: The algorithm uses argument reduction with a better approximation of pi, so cos(pi+eps) is computed as -cos(eps).

Answer (score 6):

Any error in `math.pi` vs. π (there always is some) makes very little difference in one case `math.cos(math.pi)` and is quite significant in `math.cos(math.pi/2)`.

---

**The curve is flat**

When `math.cos(x)` is very near 1.0, the curve is very flat: the slope is "close" to zero.  About *47 million* floating point `x` values near π have a `cos(x)` mathematically more than -1.0, yet their value is closer to -1.0 than the next encodable value of -0.99999999999999988897...

**The curve's slope is 1**

With `x` near π and `math.cos(x/2)` near 0.0, the cosine curve has a |slope| "close" to one. Both the next smaller and next larger encodable `x` have a different `cos(x/2)`.

**Conclusion**

When the |result| of `sin(x), cos(x)` is near 1.0, *many* nearby `x` values will report 1.0.

This would be true even if some `x` value was incredible close to π.

For `x` near π (like `math.pi`) and `y = |cos(x)|`, we need about twice the precision in `y` to see an imprecision in `x`.

Comment: I'd say it's not just the flatness but also that floats are orders of orders of magnitude denser around 0 than they are around 1.

Comment: I think you mean "`sin(x)` / `cos(x)`" or  "`sin(x)` or `cos(x)`" instead of `sin(x)/cos(x)`? I.e., both, not division?

Comment: How did you count? I assume [like this](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bVBLCoMwEKXbnGJ2GqqtFgpF8CxF1GCgJhJHjJSepBs37aF6mmpitb-s3uR9ZnjXe9VhIUXf3xpk_uGx2vOykgqhTLAgJMsZpLIR6HYe6GONicIRoGwTldU0IjA8o4AYAjPpAU1SM7cFP-Umb5PK2tUU4hg661zc6xjC-WuMMAaRa0wY5srV72uNsFJ8uIs5ZxMQeReHEmKP9UPP-is-AS4Y_Uf632wwk9vdr_eTXcy2vanEV5lP)?

Comment: @KellyBundy 1) Yes it contributes - but even a flat curve `y=g(x)`,near 0,0 has multiple `x` mapping to `y`.  2) Updated 3) Yes, counted like that.

Answer (score 1):

Two reasons:

1. I think you know this, but it bears repeating: *You did not take the cosine of π/2.*  You tried to, I know, but you didn't.  You took the cosine of 1.5707963267948965579989817342720925807952880859375, which is very close to π/2, but it is not *exactly* π/2.  And the cosine of that number, as `math.cos` correctly told you, is a small number close to but not exactly equal to 0.  If you could represent π/2 more accurately, you could get a result closer to 0, but under the present circumstances you can't represent π/2 any more accurately than that: IEEE-754 floating point has finite precision, and that number 1.570…375 is the best you can do.
2. In computer programming (as in life in general), when you do something wrong, sometimes you can get away with it.  When something is not guaranteed to work, that doesn't mean that it is guaranteed not to work.  When you took cos(π), you got "lucky", and you got an answer of 1.0, even though in that case you were actually taking cos(3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875).  (If you had more precision to play with, you would have discovered that cos(3.141…875) is actually about -0.9999999999999999999999999999999925, but that number isn't representable either, and rounds to 1.0.)

And, in fact, if you dig even deeper, these results aren't random.  Other answers explain why, mathematically, even though you can't represent π or π/2 exactly, you can get a closer result when taking the cosine of one than the other.